# Discrepancy in results when using k-means and plotting the distance matrix. Why?

Tags: r

I am doing cluster of some data in R Studio. I am having a problem with results of K-means Cluster Analysis and plotting Hierarchical Clustering. So when I use function kmeans, I get 4 groups with 10, 20, 30 and 6 observations. Nevertheless, when I plot the dendogram, I get 4 groups but with different numbers of observations: 23, 26, 10 and 7.

Have you ever found a problem like this?

Here you are my code:

```
mydata<-scale(mydata0)

# K-Means Cluster Analysis
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 4) # 4 cluster solution
# get cluster means
aggregate(mydata,by=list(fit$cluster),FUN=mean)
# append cluster assignment
mydatafinal <- data.frame(mydata, fit$cluster)

fit$size
[1] 10 20 30  6

# Ward Hierarchical Clustering
d <- dist(mydata, method = "euclidean") # distance matrix
fit2 <- hclust(d, method="ward.D2")
plot(fit2,cex=0.4) # display dendogram
groups <- cutree(fit2, k=4) # cut tree into 4 clusters
# draw dendogram with red borders around the 4 clusters
rect.hclust(fit2, k=4, border="red")
```

Answer (score 0):

Results of k-means and hierarchical clustering do not need to be the same in every scenario.

Just to give an example, everytime you run k-means the initial choice of the centroids is different and so results are different.

Answer (score 0):

This is not surprising. K-means clustering is initialised at random and can give distinct answers. Typically one tends to do several runs and then aggregate the results to check which are the 'core' clusters.

Hierarchical clustering is, in contrast, purely deterministic as there is no randomness involved. But like K-means, it is a heuristic: a set of rules is followed to create clusters with no regard to any underlying objective function (for example the intra- and inter- cluster variance vs overall variance). The way existing clusters are aggregated to individual observations is crucial in determining the size of the formed clusters (the "ward.D2" parameter you pass as method in the hclust command).

Having a properly defined objective function to optimise should give you a unique answer (or set thereof) but the problem is NP-hard, because of the sheer size (as a function of the number of observations) of the partitioning involved. This is why only heuristics exist and also why any clustering procedure should not be seen as a tool giving definitive answers but as an exploratory one.